# SAP Hana: Maximum number of row store containers (1835008) exceeded

Tags: hana

I am using SAP Hana as my datastore. I caught an exception in my Java code, as follows:

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [132]: transaction rolled back due to unavailable resource: search table error: "TN_LIVE"."XXX": line 254 col 1 (at pos 9718): [132] (range 3): transaction rolled back due to unavailable resource: "TN_LIVE"."YYY": line 300 col 1 (at pos 10317): [132] (range 3): transaction rolled back due to unavailable resource: maximum number of row store containers (1835008) exceeded
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.createException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:345)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.generateDatabaseException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:185)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.ReplyPacket.buildExceptionChain(ReplyPacket.java:100)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:1130)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:877)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.execute(CallableStatementSapDB.java:492)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.execute(CallableStatementSapDB.java:341)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.executeUpdate(CallableStatementSapDB.java:884)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.trace.CallableStatement.executeUpdate(CallableStatement.java:1163)
```

What might have caused it?

### Edit

I suspect it could be due to temp table that we used in our Stored Procs which are row store types - all our tables are column store types. This is our server specs:

1. Our hana box on AWS is 122GB
2. During the time the issue occurred free Hana RAM was approx 42GB
3. How can I edit the row store containers settings to overcome the 1835008 exceeded warning? Or some steps on how to mitigate this issues?
4. The issues got fixed automatically after restarting Hana server and approx 97GB RAM got freed
5. Is upgrading Hana box the only solution or certain tweaks are available?

This article seem to have some information on on the "Maximum number of row store containers * exceeded" -
https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/preview/en/2229994. Can anyone share what's mentioned over there?

Comment: Most commercial DB platform vendors have paid access to their support material. Based on the document, you should ensure that you're using a HANA version newer than rev. 82 (which is ancient by now) to fix the issue.

Comment: We are using HANA version 1.00.122.00.1469567304

Comment: In that case it's crucial to understand your code and your data. As said before, you're likely better off by using column store temp tables. But without knowing exactly what the code looks like, no precise help can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that the HANA internal resource management for row store tables has reached one of its limits.
Without information about what exactly you are doing and how your data gets stored it's not possible to provide the exact answer to your problem.
However, I would start looking into why you are using row store tables at all and how you change the data in it.

Comment: I guess, the only tables which are row store types are temp tables. All other tables are column store types.

Comment: You can create temporary column tables - see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Creating temporary column tables seems to fix it.